# Chrome 39.0.2171.95 Fixed Position Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, positioning

I'm having trouble making the second background image in the "Great people providing great service" section fixed position: http://www.580exec.com/

It works in Safari and Firefox, it use to work in Chrome but now it doesn't. The rest of the pages with fixed position all work in Chrome but not this particular image.

I've tried the following code already:
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

Here is the css attached to that section:

```
.cos_banner {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 576px;
    box-shadow: 0px 576px rgba(51,35,25,0.65) inset;
}

.cos_banner_parallax {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 504px;
    box-shadow: 0 576px rgba(51,35,25,0.65) inset;
    background-image: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/410423/file-1582819029-jpg/theme/banners/receptionist.jpg')  !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem that is rendering one of my apps unusable. There is a bug report but it's marked as won't-fix :-/ https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436290

Answer (score 0):

I have **removed** the **position:relative;** from the class **.cos_banner_parallax**, and it seem to be working.

```
.cos_banner_parallax {
    /*position: relative;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 504px;
    box-shadow: 0 576px rgba(51,35,25,0.65) inset;
    background-image: url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/410423/file-1582819029-jpg/theme/banners/receptionist.jpg')  !important;
}
```